# Advice on what platform and technology to use: distributed bookkeeping app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, google-docs

I have an opportunity to learn some new tech to write this code. Basic requirements:

- users in various locations worldwide
- user control: control who can see, edit, approve various sheets/accounts/transactions within a sheet
- parse bank statement files into the system
- generate reports
- robust logging: who enters, edits, approves transactions
- secure, reliable data storage
- ability to serve from the Internet, or a local network web server

I was going to use a Google Docs Spreadsheet with scripts, but I can't see the user control being rigid enough.

At the moment I am leaning towards Java Servlets and JSP with Google App Engine.

What would you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlets and JSP are good technology but fairly basic / low level. You might find it more interesting and productive to try on of the newer web-based frameworks.

Some ideas:

- [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) might suit this kind of application pretty well, it's a framework for rich internet applications that gives you much more sophisticated components than you could implement with plain JSPs.
- I've also heard very good thinks about the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).
- If you are feeling really adventurous and fancy picking up a new language (Clojure) then [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) is also a great web framework in the making.

Comment: Thanks mikera, will look into those!

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement here that may be a gotcha for App Engine is "ability to serve from the Internet, or a local network web server". What exactly do you mean? If this is something that your users are going to want to install locally then App Engine is out of the question.

Any sort of java based solution is going to fit all of the rest of your requirements. Since you have a lot of logging/security, you may want to look at Spring MVC with Spring Security or even Grails (which also supports spring security).

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at Spring, Vaadin looking good so far